# Why do I get object HTMLButtonElement with this event listener code?

Tags: javascript

I want both the "this" outside and the this inside to be the same, however on the inside "this" gives me object HTMLButtonElement. What does HTMLButtonElement mean and why does it not console.log what it prints on the outside?

```js
function fanta() {
  console.log('outside', this);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`this is the inside this ${this}`);
  }, 1000)
}

const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const two = document.querySelector('.two');

one.addEventListener('click', fanta);
two.addEventListener('click', fanta);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get your question now. Ok theres 2 different things happening here - first the outside is running `console.log` - that doesn't always call `.toString()` but with the string interpolation, it does. That the difference.

If you follow it - the event triggers with the element as `this` in your `fanta` callback. From there the arrow function captures that `this`.

You can change what `this` is in `fanta` by using

```
one.addEventListener('click', fanta.bind(something));
```

Comment: i believe this answer is incorrect as it doesn't work!

Comment: @DCR specifics please.

Comment: you've got it now!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to bind anything  your code is fine. It's just the way you're trying to console.log(this)

```js
 function fanta() {
       console.log('outside', this);
       setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('this is the inside this = ',this);
      }, 1000)
      }


          const one = document.querySelector('.one');
          const two = document.querySelector('.two');


          one.addEventListener('click', fanta);
          two.addEventListener('click', fanta);
```

```html
<button class="one">one</button>
<button class="two">two</button>
```